# Trouble in understanding this syntax

Tags: java

I have come across with this syntax while reading some others code

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    { 
         put("a", "b");
    }
};
```

I know how to use `anonymous inner class` but this seems something different.  Could somebody explain me how exactly the above works and how it is different from `Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); map.put("a", "b");` ?

Comment: Is is also sometimes called double brace initialization.

Comment: Thanks assylias, Tried to search before I post it, but could not find.

Comment: I searched on "[java] +double +brace" - unless you know the alternative name, it's not easy to find! ;-)

Comment: Simply search for "double braces java"; takes me right to the relevant page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are basically creating a anonymous class instance and specifying an [instance initializer](http://blog.ryanrampersad.com/2009/11/18/static-and-instance-initializers-in-java/). Think of it in terms of a normal class, e.g.:

```
class Person {

  String age, name;

  List<String> hobbies;

  {
    hobbies = new ArrayList<String>();
  }

  public Person(String name, String age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  } 

}
```

What do you think the above is doing? Your anonymous class is doing something similar. :)

Comment: Correct, as soon as `new Person(...)` called, even hobbies gets initialized along with name and age. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, you got that right. Also make sure you go through the thread mentioned in the comment to your original post.

Answer (score 2):

As Sanjay T. Sharma clearly explained, it's creating anonymous class instance. In fact, it is extending `java.util.HashMap`. Consider the following code:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> mapSimple = new HashMap<String, String>();
        System.out.println("Simple java.util.HashMap:");
        System.out.println("\t" + mapSimple.getClass());

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {
            {
                put("a", "b");
            }
        };

        System.out.println("Anonymous class based on java.util.HashMap:");
        System.out.println("\t" + map.getClass());
        System.out.println("\t" + map.getClass().getSuperclass());
    }
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
Simple java.util.HashMap:
    class java.util.HashMap
Anonymous class based on java.util.HashMap:
    class com.test.Demo$1
    class java.util.HashMap
```

Pay attention to the name of such anonymous class, and that this class extends `java.util.HashMap`.